# Decrypting String in .Net C++

Tags: .net, encryption, frameworks, c++-cli

I'm coming to you with small problem. Actually I'm trying to make a function which will be able to decrypt string in .NET C++. Here is my function's code:

```cpp
array<Byte>^ chipherbytes;
array<Byte>^ plainbytes2;
array<Byte>^ plainkey;
SymmetricAlgorithm^ desObj;
desObj = Rijndael::Create();
chipherbytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(dataGridView1->CurrentCell->Value->ToString());
plainkey = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
desObj->Key = plainkey;
desObj->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;
desObj->Padding=PaddingMode::PKCS7;
MemoryStream^ ms1 = gcnew MemoryStream(chipherbytes);
CryptoStream^ cs1 = gcnew CryptoStream(ms1, desObj->CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode::Read);
cs1->Read(chipherbytes, 0, chipherbytes->Length); //<- in this line is problem
plainbytes2 = ms1->ToArray();
cs1->Close();
ms1->Close();
textBox1->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(plainbytes2);
```

but when i'm starting debugging and later i'm turn on this function then program is crashing and is comunication "System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The complement is invalid and cannot be removed." and it is showing in marked label. Anybody can advise me?

**EDIT:**

Here is encryption part of code:

```cpp
cipherData = textBox6->Text;
    plainbytes = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes(cipherData);
    plainkey = Encoding::ASCII->GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
    desObj->Key = plainkey;
    //choose other appropriate modes (CBC,CFB,CTS,ECB,OFB)
    desObj->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;
    desObj->Padding = PaddingMode::PKCS7;
    MemoryStream^ ms = gcnew MemoryStream();
    CryptoStream^ cs = gcnew CryptoStream(ms,desObj->CreateEncryptor(),CryptoStreamMode::Write);
    cs->Write(plainbytes,0,plainbytes->Length);
    cs->Close();
    chipherbytes = ms->ToArray();
    ms->Close();
    textBox7->Text = Encoding::ASCII->GetString(chipherbytes);
```

And by the way i wanto to send encryption data to mysql database and then download it from database and decrypt it.

Comment: As you are using the AES algorithm in **CBC** mode you need to use an initialization vector (iv) that has to be the same on encryption- and decryption side. In your decryption code I do not see any "IV". Th ohelp you in this case it would be helpful to see a) the encryption part and b) a full set of sample data (plaintext, key, iv and ciphertext), thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr i add all about what you said in post please i need ur help because i have tomorrow interview

Comment: You must not convert the ciphertext to a string with ASCII encoding in the encryption part, since this will **corrupt** the data. If you want to convert the binary ciphertext into a text, you need a suitable binary-to-text encoding, such as Base64: `System::String^ ciphertext = Convert::ToBase64String(chipherbytes);` Similarly, in the decryption part before decrypting the ciphertext, it must be Base64 decoded: `array<Byte>^ chipherbytes = Convert::FromBase64String(ciphertext);`

Comment: In addition, the **implicitly** generated IV must be determined in the encryption part: `System::String^ IV = Convert::ToBase64String(desObj->IV);` In the decryption part, this IV must be applied: `desObj->IV = Convert::FromBase64String(IV);` The IV is not secret and can be passed to the recipient unencrypted along with the ciphertext. To avoid passing two values, in practice IV and ciphertext are often concatenated (the recipient must then separate them).